# MongoDB $ifNull conditional with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, mgo

I'm struggling porting a query from the mongo console to my Go code.
I'm new to MongoDB so there might be additional mistakes I haven't taken into account.

Sample data 'users' collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592400188d84961b7f34b0cd"), "username" : "randomUser2", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -17.282573, 63.755657 ] } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592400188d84961b7f34b0ce"), "username" : "randomUser1", "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [ -17.634135, 65.705665 ] } }
```

Sample data 'newscounter' collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592400188d84961b7f34b0cd"), "count" : 14 }
```

The query in mongo looks like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
     { $geoNear: { 
         near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [-21.861198,64.120877] },
         distanceField: "distance",
         maxDistance: myDistance * 1000,
         spherical: true }
     },
    {
        $sort: { "distance": 1 }
    },
    {
     $lookup: {
        from: "newscounter",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "news_count" }
    },
    {
        $unwind: { path: "$news_count", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
    },
    {
        $project : { 
            "id": 1,
            "username": 1,
            "distance": 1,
            "news_count": { $ifNull : ["$news_count.count", 0] }
        }
    }
])
```

The output is (I used random values for the calculated distance field here):

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592400188d84961b7f34b0cd"), "username" : "randomUser2", "distance" : 123, "news_count" : 14 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("592400188d84961b7f34b0ce"), "username" : "randomUser1", "distance" : 456, "news_count" : 0 }
```

The part I've trouble with is the $ifNull in the $project stage.

How do I build the $ifNull line in Go using the mgo package?

I tried with:

```
"news_count": bson.M{
    "$ifNull": [2]interface{}{"$news_count.count", 0},
}
```

but it returns always an empty string for the news_count field.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT [solved]:

The issue was silly, I had the wrong `type` for the `news_count` field in the Go `struct`.

For the sake of completeness the pipeline in Go is:

```
p := []bson.M{
        bson.M{
            "$geoNear": bson.M{
                "near":          bson.M{"type": "Point", "coordinates": center},
                "distanceField": "distance",
                "maxDistance":   maxDistance,
                "spherical":     true,
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$sort": bson.M{
                "distance": 1,
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$lookup": bson.M{
                "from":         "newscount",
                "localField":   "_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as":           "news_count",
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$unwind": bson.M{
                "path": "$news_count",
                "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true,
            },
        },
        bson.M{
            "$project": bson.M{
                "_id":      1,
                "username": 1,
                "distance": 1,
                "news_count": bson.M{
                    "$ifNull": []interface{}{"$news_count.count", 0.0},
                },
            },
        },
    }
```

The result `struct`:

```
type Result struct {
          ID        bson.ObjectId  `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
          Username  string         `json:"username" bson:"username"`
          Distance  int64          `json:"distance" bson:"distance"`
          NewsCount int64          `json:"news_count" bson:"news_count"`
      }
```

Comment: That seems to be right. What about `[]interface{}{"$news_count", 0}` just for kicks? Failing that, can you show in the context of your entire pipeline reproduction. More to the point are you sure the `$unwind` is doing the correct thing?

Comment: Same result, I had already tried that. I added $unwind cause the results without would be
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("5924001e8d84961b7f34b111"), "username" : "xyz", "distance" : 123, "news_count" : [ { "count" : 14 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5924001d8d84961b7f34b104"), "username" : "abc", "distance" : 123, "news_count" : [ ] }`
And I would like to have a single field rather that an array.

Comment: Doh. Glad you edited the comment. Now the problem is clear. Is there only every 1 result as the result of the `$lookup`

Comment: I just checked, it works for me. You must show all your code, the error is somewhere else.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm sorry but my English is failing me I guess, I don't understand your question...

Comment: Will it always be `news_count" : [ { "count" : 14 } ]` or `news_count" : [ ]` But **never** `news_count" : [ { "count" : 14 }, { "count": 12 } ]`? So "users" to "newcounter" collections relationship is `1:1` and not `1:many`

Comment: Point is you should be able to use `$arrayElemAt` instead of doing `$unwind`. I still think you should try the pipeline simply dropping the last `$project` stage and see what happens. I'm thinking if you are showing output up to `$unwind` that is okay, then that stage is the issue. And if the code is running through the shell just fine, then your Go code is the issue. I think you should post that code. So the full pipeline listing.

Comment: Yes, it's a `1:1` relationship, basically what I'm trying to do is to use the aggregation to avoid the need to query the 'newscounter' collection for each user returned by the geospatial query.
I'll edit the question with the relevant Go code in a bit.

Comment: I found the issue... The `struct` I was using had the wrong type for the `news_count` field.
Spent a couple of hours trying to rewrite the pipeline before asking here, and then it was a silly mistake.
For the sake of completeness I have added the Go code to the question.
Sorry for wasting your time, and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `news_count` projection works, the error is somewhere else in the code which you haven't posted.

See this full, working example:

```
cu := sess.DB("").C("users")
cnc := sess.DB("").C("newscounter")

he := func(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

he(cu.Insert(
    bson.M{
        "_id":      bson.ObjectIdHex("592400188d84961b7f34b0ce"),
        "username": "randomuser1",
        "location": bson.M{
            "type":        "Point",
            "coordinates": []interface{}{-17.634135, 65.705665},
        },
    },
    bson.M{
        "_id":      bson.ObjectIdHex("592400188d84961b7f34b0cd"),
        "username": "randomuser2",
        "location": bson.M{
            "type":        "Point",
            "coordinates": []interface{}{-17.282573, 63.755657},
        },
    },
))
he(cnc.Insert(
    bson.M{
        "_id":   bson.ObjectIdHex("592400188d84961b7f34b0cd"),
        "count": 14,
    },
))

pipe := cu.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {
        "$geoNear": bson.M{
            "near": bson.M{
                "type":        "Point",
                "coordinates": []interface{}{-21.861198, 64.120877},
            },
            "distanceField": "distance",
            "maxDistance":   123456789,
            "spherical":     true,
        },
    },
    {
        "$sort": bson.M{"distance": 1},
    },
    {
        "$lookup": bson.M{
            "from":         "newscounter",
            "localField":   "_id",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as":           "news_count",
        },
    },
    {
        "$unwind": bson.M{
            "path": "$news_count",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true,
        },
    },
    {
        "$project": bson.M{
            "id":       1,
            "username": 1,
            "distance": 1,
            "news_count": bson.M{
                "$ifNull": []interface{}{"$news_count.count", 0},
            },
        },
    },
})

it := pipe.Iter()

fmt.Println()
m := bson.M{}
for it.Next(&m) {
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println()
}
he(it.Err())
```

Output:

```
map[_id:ObjectIdHex("592400188d84961b7f34b0cd") username:randomuser2 distance:227534.08191011765 news_count:14]

map[username:randomuser1 distance:266222.98643136176 news_count:0 _id:ObjectIdHex("592400188d84961b7f34b0ce")]
```